# Spring boot refresh issue when using reactjs and spring boot together

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

Using reactjs and spring as monolithic application.. Facing the whitelabel page error when refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own questions so that people like me will easily find solution for this issue.

The fix is we need to forward the view in IndexController to resolve the whitepage label error in reactjs and spring:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class IndexController implements ErrorController {
    
    private static final String PATH = "/error";
    
    @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
    public ModelAndView saveLeadQuery() {           
        return new ModelAndView("forward:/");
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return PATH;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Don't need to accept this answer. Does not have enough information. OG post does not include any code and explanation not enough